# Can you Help me understand what I have done wrong with this trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

The trigger should look at all contacts on an account and find the median NPS Score and update the field on the account called Median NPS score.

```
trigger NPSScore on Contact (before insert) {
     for (Contact contact : trigger.new){
        Set<Id> ContactId = new Set<Id>();
        List<Integer> contactvalues = new List<Integer>();
        for(Contact c:[Select Id, NPS_Rating__c from Contact where NPS_Rating__c != null ])

Integer sizeOfList = contactvalues.size();
Integer index = sizeOfList - 1;
Decimal median = 0.0;

// sort the list first
contactvalues.sort();

//Calculate median
if (Math.mod(sizeOfList, 2) == 0) {
   median = (contactValues[(index-1)/2] + contactValues[(index/2)+1])/2;
}else{
   median = contactvalues[(index+1)/2];
}

system.debug('the median is: '+median);
        account.Median_NPS_Score__c = median;
     }
}
```

Comment: Is this a sub question or just the same with the post on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5992/trying-to-write-a-trigger-to-update-a-parent-object-from-child/5994#5994  You question is the same about how to update parent record from the Trigger on the child object.

Comment: What actually does happen? What have you tried? From the looks of things, you aren't selecting out the Account and separately updating it, which you'll probably need to do. I assume you are getting a compile error?

Comment: Yes, this is a sub question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below,

```
`trigger NPSScore on Contact (after insert, after update) {
    //find out Contact list updated or inserted
    Set ContactIds = new Set();

    for (Contact con : Trigger.new) {
        if(con.NPS_Rating__c != null) {
            ContactIds.add(con.Id);
        }
    }
```

//find out the parent Account list of Contact
Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Contact con:[Select AccountId from Contact Where AccountId != null And Id IN:ContactIds ]) {
    AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
}

//for each Account, calculate Median value and insert to the Account
List<Account> accountforupdate = new List<Account>();
for(Account acc:[Select Id, (Select NPS_Rating__c from Contacts where NPS_Rating__c != null ) from Account Where Id IN:AccountIds]) {
    List<Integer> contactvalues = new List<Integer>();
    for(Contact con:acc.Contacts) {
        contactvalues.add(Integer.valueOf(con.NPS_Rating__c));
    }

    Integer sizeOfList = contactvalues.size();
    Integer index = sizeOfList - 1;
    Decimal median = 0.0;

    // sort the list first
    contactvalues.sort();
    //Calculate median
    if (Math.mod(sizeOfList, 2) == 0) {
       median = (contactValues[(index-1)/2] + contactValues[(index/2)+1])/2;
    }else{
       median = contactvalues[(index+1)/2];
    }
    system.debug('the median is: '+median);
    acc.Median_NPS_Score__c = median;

    accountforupdate.add(acc);                  
}
update accountforupdate;

}`

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions about the code. It worked for me for insert or update, but I haven't tested it in a batch way.

Comment: Jia, I am getting this error:
Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found 'ContactIds' at line 3 column 8

Comment: Jia, I figured it out! Yep, and I felt like a superstar. LOL Thanks for your help. I promise to learn more before my next project/question! :D